# AWS Route 53 email setup with EC2 OR webmail/email service provider

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I bought domain names on AWS Route53.
I launched the websites on S2.

Now, I cannot setup new email addresses.
SES/EC2 are ready-to-go solutions.

I want to:

- Create new email addresses ASAP (business trip in 10 days)
- Simple daily-email, no newsletters, no mass emails
- Ready-to-go solution, no installing/configuring of complex technical systems like Linux, Ubuntu, SquirrelMail, Google Apps systems...
- I was referred by a MX record based system used by Outlook; unfortunately this service is no longer available.

Questions:

- Is there any easy and simple solution using Route 53/SES/EC2 ?
- Or, any 3rd party service that I can use ? (ideally, something free – I do not want to pay 50$/year per user)

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty straight-forward free service that I'm using called Zoho:
https://www.zoho.com/mail/

I'm new to it as well, so I can't speak to its reliability, but setup is pretty easy. It will have you verify your account by creating a record set in your 'Hosted Zone' page in Route 53.

Comment: I've just set this up for myself, I only want two email addresses for my domain and zoho's free tier seem to allow this.  I think they allow up to 10 accounts.  I'm running both accounts through GMail by forwarding / smtp.

Comment: just as a note, i've been using this service for almost a year now: service and support are really good and it's _still_ free

Comment: Allows 25 users on the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

for creating **webmail** there's a  **WorkMail** option on aws services. you can create an email account there.
first click on add organization button . then go to quick setup. fill the requirements. after it's done click on the organization name that you already created and create a user.
enter a username and password that you want. after creating user , you can find the webmail url on "organization setting tab".
the **WorkMail** can integrates nicely with **SES**.